# XQuery 3.1 evaluation using SaxonJS 2.5 (browser)

Tags: javascript, xml, xquery, saxon-js, xquery-3.1

### What I want

I need to create a **Javascript function** that allows to get the result of evaluating an [XQuery 3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/) expression against an XML.

The function:

- Must receive two parameters: the **XML document** (String) and the **XQuery expression** (String).
- Must return the result of the **XQuery evaluation** (String).

```js
function evaluateXQuery(xmlStr, xqueryStr) {
  // XQuery 3.1 evaluation
  return resultStr;
}
```

Example:

```js
// XML Document
const xml = 
`<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title>XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <price>24.99</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>`

// XQuery
const xquery = 
`for $x in /bookstore/book
where $x/price>25
return $x/title`;

// XQuery 3.1 evaluation
const output = evaluateXQuery(xml, xquery);

// Output
console.log(output); // "<title>XQuery Kick Start</title>"
```

### What I did

I used [SaxonJS 2.5](https://www.saxonica.com/download/javascript.xml) (browser version) to evaluate XPath expressions, but I can't find anything in the [documentation](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html) regarding the evaluation of XQuery queries.

To evaluate XPath expressions I made the following function:

```js
async function evaluteXPath(xmlStr, xpathStr) {
  const doc = await SaxonJS.getResource({
    text: xmlStr,
    type: 'xml'
  });

  return SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(xpathStr, doc);
}
```

I also made a similar function to perform XSLT transformations using [`SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate`](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!api/xpathEvaluate).

I am looking for something similar to the above, but applied to XQuery.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: As Mike told you in his answer, SaxonJS doesn't support XQuery 3.1. https://github.com/FontoXML/fontoxpath claims to support it, however.

Answer (score 1):

SaxonJS does not include XQuery support: only XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1.

Your particular example query can of course be written easily in XPath:

```
/bookstore/book[price>25]/title
```

Comment: I will have to look for another library. The function is for an education tool and XQuery is a requirement. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The only project I know of is XQIB, but I think it hasn't been updated for many years and is unlikely to support XQuery 3.1. Let us know if you find anything.

Comment: I just learned via Martin that FontoXPath has some XQuery support. Incomplete, and the exact conformance level is not well documented, but unlike XQIB it's an active and lively project.